# What to do with unused air fare (Hawaiian airline)

Tags: airline

Beginning this year, I found a fantastic deal from the U.S. to Japan for less than $1000 via Hawaiian airline. Sadly, the next day (literally the next day) after I booked the ticket (travel time around February) my school announced that they would change the graduation exam for this year which conflict with my original travel plan. Worrying I would fail the exam right after vacation, I decided to not hop on the plane and instead studying for my exam.

Now, I talked to Hawaiian airline agent and they said I can still rebook the ticket within one year and they will credit the unused fare -$350 rebooking fee. Effectively, I have about $600 to use... Unfortunately, the cheapest Hawaiian airline ticket to Japan is closed to $1400 while other airline can get to the same destination for ~$830.

Should I pay Hawaiian airline to book my trip to Japan or forget about these credits and choose the cheapest options... One caveat is that I will have two more family members traveling with me, and they are not tied to any airline yet, so paying $1400 for them to flight Hawaiian airline with me seems a non starter... Thoughts, comment?

Comment: Does the airline have your passport number, SSN, or other uniquely identifying information? Otherwise, selling the ticket could be an alternate solution  http://www.ctvnews.ca/canada/toronto-man-finds-woman-with-ex-girlfriend-s-name-for-free-trip-around-world-1.2151474

Comment: That is a very creative idea!

Comment: @DJohnM, they probably have name/DOB/gender.  That's what I'm asked when I book a flight.  If they sold the ticket, it'd have to be to someone with that same information.  The TSA checks your ticket against your id.  Since your id probably has a picture, the buyer should look a lot like the seller.  OP, do you have an identical twin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you have paid is sunk cost. One should discount it.

> the cheapest Hawaiian airline ticket to Japan is closed to $1400 while other airline can get to the same destination for ~$830.

So effectively the Hawaiian airline will cost $800 [$1400 - $600]. Other is costing around $830. Not much of a difference. So see other factors, convenience in terms of times, etc to pick the airline.

> One caveat is that I will have two more family members traveling with me, and they are not tied to any airline yet, so paying $1400 for them to flight Hawaiian airline

In order for you to save max of $30 [difference between $830 and $800] ... you are asking other to spend around $1140 [$1400-$830 twice]. This does not make sense.